# Is there a way to prevent a WebView from losing session information on reload?

Tags: android, android-webview, single-sign-on, saml

So I have been asked to help implement Simple Saml SSO integration into our mobile apps and am having issues with keeping the session alive after logging into our Android Apps.

**NOTE: I bet there is a better way to do this but this is how I was instructed to implement it.**

I have created a WebView in my main activity that loads the Service provider's site. When the user logins correctly the WebView is then redirected by the service provider to a keep-alive url that is specific to our application. This WebView's visibility is then set to hidden, and it keeps the session alive in the "background"

The Service provider provides a keep alive expiration date that we set a timer to schedule the WebView to reload/refresh so that the session stays active.

What I am noticing is that on the first reload of the WebView will redirect back to the Service Provider's login url. The redirect is the proper behavior for the type of SSO we are doing if the user is not logged in. The user was successfully logged in previously, but on the first reload it is like the WebView has lost all the previous session info/data.

**Is there a WebView Setting I can set to make the session persistent between reloads?**

I have already implemented this on our Apple apps and the WebView in Swift is able to keep the session alive on each refresh.

I have confirmed that the WebView's url before the refresh is the correct keep alive url.

**----UPDATE-----**

So I have tried using the WebView's evaluateJavascript function to set the window's location to the keep-alive url and the same loss of session info happens. I then tried to call the window's location reload function and still no session info preservation.

I was wondering if Chrome app would have the same issue, so I tried logging into the Service Provider's url in the regular Chrome app. Once I was logged in I then tried refreshing on the keep alive url and the session info was persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to figure out it was something we were doing with our test Service Provider's URL and has been resolved once we started using the real Service Provider's URL.